# Convert tuple with quotes to csv like string

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv, quotes

How to convert tuple

```
text = ('John', '"n"', '"ABC 123\nDEF, 456GH\nijKl"\r\n', '"Johny\nIs\nHere"')
```

to csv format

```
out = '"John", """n""", """ABC 123\\nDEF, 456\\nijKL\\r\\n""", """Johny\\nIs\\nHere"""'
```

or even omitting the special chars at the end

```
out = '"John", """n""", """ABC 123\\nDEF, 456\\nijKL""", """Johny\\nIs\\nHere"""'
```

I came up with this monster

```
out1 = ','.join(f'""{t}""' if t.startswith('"') and t.endswith('"')
                           else f'"{t}"' for t in text)
out2 = out1.replace('\n', '\\n').replace('\r', '\\r')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get pretty close to what you want with the csv and io modules from the standard library:

- use csv to correctly encode the delimiters and handle the quoting rules; it only writes to a file handle
- use io.StringIO for that file handle to get the resulting CSV as a string

```py
import csv
import io

f = io.StringIO()

text = ("John", '"n"', '"ABC 123\nDEF, 456GH\nijKl"\r\n', '"Johny\nIs\nHere"')

writer = csv.writer(f)
writer.writerow(text)

csv_str = f.getvalue()
csv_repr = repr(csv_str)

print("CSV_STR")
print("=======")
print(csv_str)

print("CSV_REPR")
print("========")
print(csv_repr)
```

and that prints:

```
CSV_STR
=======
John,"""n""","""ABC 123
DEF, 456GH
ijKl""
","""Johny
Is
Here"""

CSV_REPR
========
'John,"""n""","""ABC 123\nDEF, 456GH\nijKl""\r\n","""Johny\nIs\nHere"""\r\n'
```

- `csv_str` is what you'd see in a file if you wrote directly to a file you opened for writing, it is **true CSV**
- `csv_repr` is kinda what you asked for when you showed us `out`, but not quite.  Your example included "doubly escaped" newlines `\\n` and carriage returns `\\r\\n`.  CSV doesn't need to escape those characters any more because the entire field is quoted.  If you need that, you'll need to do it yourself with something like:

  ```py
  csv_repr.replace(r"\r", r"\\r").replace(r"\n", r"\\n")
  ```

  but again, that's not necessary for valid CSV.

  Also, I don't know how to make the writer include an *initial space* before every field after the first field, like the spaces you show between "John" and "n" and then after "n" in:

  ```py
  out = 'John, """n""", ...'
  ```

  The reader can be configured to expect and ignore an initial space, with [Dialect.skipinitialspace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.skipinitialspace), but I don't see any options for the writer.